# How to convert ImageView in res to Base64 String, in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, base64, encode

i want request to Flask server.
so, i converted a img to JSON data in Kotlin(Android Studio)

Although JSON data is well sent and received from the server, the size of the transmitted data is five times larger than the original data.

what should i do to get exact data from server??

**Simple Server Code(python)...**

```
    print(len(request.json['file']))
    img_data = base64.b64decode(request.json['file'])
    filename = 'received_now_starry_night.png'
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(img_data)


    dic = {
        "msg":"hello"
    }
    return jsonify(dic)
```

**Android Studio, kotlin Code...**

```
   val bitmap:Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.starry_night)
   val bos:ByteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
   bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos)
   val image:ByteArray = bos.toByteArray()

   val base64Encoded = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(image)

   val rootObject = JSONObject()
   rootObject.put("file", base64Encoded)
```

Comment: You already converted a res drawable to Base64 string and it works, right?

Comment: i have no idea about that kotlin code. you mean  that the first code of the kotlin code?

Comment: it looks like you have a valid kotlin code, that convert image to base64 string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert an image to Base64 String :

You can also create a resized Bitmap and compress it to decrease the size

```
    private fun CreateImageStringFromBitmap(): String {

        val bitmap:Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.starry_night)

        val resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
            bitmap:Bitmap, (desired width).toInt(),
            (desired height).toInt(), true
        )

        val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        resized.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 75, stream)
        val byteArray: ByteArray = stream.toByteArray()

        return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT)
    }
```